# Running ArcGIS Engine in Java 7?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-engine, java

Does anyone know if it's possible to run ArcGIS Engine 10.2 in Java 7 ?

Currently in Java 6, I need to use both ArcGIS Engine 10.2 and Java 7 functions in the same standalone program. (I don't talk about AddIn or Geoprocessing Tools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. Alternatively, we need to call a Java 7 or 8 executable JAR from the ArcObjects Java 6.